# Oracle Case in Where clause having omitted the Else expression, results?

Tags: oracle, null, case, where-clause

What does the following statement equate to when `table2.level = 3` for some rows?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1, table2
 WHERE table1.value1 =
       CASE table2.id
           WHEN 1 THEN table2.value1(+)
           WHEN 2 THEN table2.value2(+)
       END
```

[Oracle DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql#syntax) state that "CASE returns NULL" if none of the cases evaluate to `TRUE` and the `ELSE` expression is omitted, but substituting the `CASE` expression by `NULL` yields `0` results instead.

The result, by the way, is that the query results omit the optional table2 results for rows in which `table2.level = 3` as if the entire equation after `AND` results in `TRUE` (for those particular rows).

Can someone elaborate on how/why this works?

**Edit:** Replacing the `(+)` operator with the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax helped me gain insight in what it means when the `CASE` expression returns `NULL`.

The following statements are equal if `table2.id IN (1,2,3)`

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
           ON table1.value1 =
              CASE table2.id
                  WHEN 1 THEN table2.value1
                  WHEN 2 THEN table2.value2
              END
```

---

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
           ON table1.value1 =
              CASE table2.id
                  WHEN 1 THEN table2.value1
                  WHEN 2 THEN table2.value2
                  WHEN 3 THEN NULL
              END
```

---

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
           ON table1.value1 =
              CASE table2.id
                  WHEN 1 THEN table2.value1
                  WHEN 2 THEN table2.value2
                  ELSE NULL
              END
```

I think that answers the question;
it does equate to `NULL` but only for the rows not in the `CASE` expression, still outer joining the table2 results when `table2.id = 1 OR table2.id = 2`

Comment: Side note, you shouldn't be using this archaic old left join syntax that is proprietary of oracle (DB2 happens to support it also) database.

Comment: Please stop using the old, ancient implicit joins. Even Oracle recommends to use the explicit `outer join` over the proprietary `(+)` operator

Comment: Please [provide an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This code is invalid (`level` is an invalid identifier, and beyond that it gets ORA-01416 or ORA-01417). Include sample data and the result you get from both version of the query.